# Android, accesing a textview from a surfaceview

Tags: android, textview, surfaceview

I have an activity, this activity name is Game, it's xml file is composed by two views control, first of them it's a TextView called Texto and the second one is a SurfaceView created by me called Juego.
The Juego view has an onTouchListener event, and i want to send a text to the control called Texto everytime the user clicks on the control Juego.

I have all the "structure" created but i can't "communicate" from Juego to Texto, every thing i try i get an error.

Thx for help in advance,

Comment: Please show the relevant code, what you tried and the errors that resulted. If you give your question more context, you'll get better answers.

Comment: check this link i think helpful-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779215/androidhow-to-add-a-button-in-surface-view

In LinearLayout add TextView add when Surfaceview click Then OnTouch
Dynamically create Textview (Add in LinearLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener such as
`onViewClick(String text)`. Create instance of this on your `SurfaceView` and in constructor get this listener as parameter. Now call this listener wherever you want to update the textView.

In you activity class, implement onViewClick listener and in method do:

```
public void onViewClick(String text){
 TextTo.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your help, I am starting studying Android so please let me know your anserws with a bit more detail. I can't find onViewClick listener.