# dynamic buttons and action listener in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to create a dynamic button and have to access it in action listener. I mean to say the id of it and have to perform required action.Can any one help me please

```
package com.check.widget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

 public class DynamicWidgetActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int size=10;
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
    ll.addView(tv);

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText("weeeeeeeeeee~!");
    ll.addView(et);

    Button buttons[] = new Button[size];             
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        buttons[i]=new Button(this);
        ll.addView(buttons[i]);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: [Android: How to programmatically add button to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776057/android-how-to-programmatically-add-button-to-view)

As far as accessing the Button Id. It probably wont have one unless you set it.

Comment: how to set the id and how to use it. I am not able to understand

Comment: read the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html then do a search (CTRL+F) for setId