# ImageView be a square with dynamic width?

Tags: android, dynamic, size, imageview

I have a GridView with ImageViews inside. I have 3 of them for each row. I can set correctly the width with WRAP_CONTENT and scaleType = CENTER_CROP, but I don't know how to set the ImageView's size to be a square. Here's what I did until now, it seems to be ok except the height, that is "static":

```
imageView = new ImageView(context);     
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300));
```

I'm doing it inside an adapter.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The best option is to subclass `ImageView` yourself, overriding the measure pass:

```
public class SquareImageView  extends ImageView {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: If I set padding // margin, I get a white border.. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" @Waza_Be

Comment: Shouldn't it be set as the min(width,height) instead?

Comment: It's a tiny optimization, but checking that the width and the height are different could prevent another measurement pass.

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        // Optimization so we don't measure twice unless we need to
        if (width != height) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
        }
    }

Comment: Answer is explained in this page http://codesofjunaid.blogspot.com/2017/04/android-responsive-square-image-view.html

Answer (score 102):

The other answer works fine. This is just an extension of bertucci's solution to make an ImageView with square width and height with respect to xml inflated layout.

Create a class, say a SquareImageView extending ImageView like this,

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

}
```

Now, in your xml do this,

```
        <com.packagepath.tothis.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/Imageview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

If you need an ImageView not to be dynamically created in program, instead, to be fixed in xml, then this implementation will be helpful.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Andro. This is precisely what I was looking for. Again, thanks for taking the time to provide a complete answer.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct, full solution.

Comment: See also a good tutorial that uses this technique: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2945946-glide-tutorial-for-android-getting-started

Answer (score 27):

Even more simple:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }    
}
```

Comment: don't forget for sdk >= 21

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

Answer (score 11):

Several of the previous answers are perfectly sufficient. I'm just adding a small optimization to both @Andro Selva and @a.bertucci's solutions here:

It's a tiny optimization, but checking that the width and the height are different could prevent another measurement pass.

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        // Optimization so we don't measure twice unless we need to
        if (width != height) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a Kotlin solution:

```
class SquareImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : ImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes){
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) = super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An squareImageView by specified width:

```
public class SquareImageViewByWidth extends AppCompatImageView {

    public SquareImageViewByWidth(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageViewByWidth(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageViewByWidth(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width= getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

     ...
}
```

---

An squareImageView by specified height:

```
    public class SquareImageViewByHeight extends AppCompatImageView {

        public SquareImageViewByHeight(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public SquareImageViewByHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public SquareImageViewByHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            int height = getMeasuredHeight();
            setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
        }

        ...
    }
```

---

An squareImageView by minimum of dimentions:

```
public class SquareImageViewByMin extends AppCompatImageView {

        public SquareImageViewByHeight(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public SquareImageViewByHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public SquareImageViewByHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int minSize = Math.min(width, height);
            setMeasuredDimension(minSize, minSize);
        }

       ...
    }
```

Comment: The use of `AppCompatImageView` in this answer is an important point.

Answer (score 1):

if someone wants the view to be not square, but proportionally resized in height (for example, 16/9 or 1/3), you can do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth()/3, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line solution -

```
layout.setMinimumHeight(layout.getWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution for Kotlin (Material.ShapeableImageView can be changed to ImageView)

```
class SquareImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ShapeableImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here all are unnecessary calling its superclass for `onMeasure`. Here is my implementation

```java
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = Math.min(width, height);
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```