# How do I make android imageview square?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm using an `ImageView` in an Android project.

Width: `match_parent`
Height: `wrap_content`

then I scale it to `fill_XY`, but the image is not square yet... what can I do?

[image]

Comment: use fixed width and height for imageview

Comment: There is another post which migth help. Have a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506275/imageview-be-a-square-with-dynamic-width

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The best way for square image is use **ConstraintLayout** with **constraintDimensionRatio** Without give fix height/width.

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: android:scaleType="centerCrop" is really a bad idea and screws up the pictures.

Comment: This worked great; didn't do centerCrop, of course.

Comment: sadly this answer does not provide the proper namespace for `app:`

Answer (score 27):

Try creating your own imageview by extending ImageView. This is how I do it:

> Icon.java file

```
public class Icon extends ImageView {

public Icon(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Icon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Icon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (measuredWidth > measuredHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredHeight, measuredHeight);
    } else {
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth);

    }

}

}
```

> xml file

```
<com.mypackage.Icon
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/screen" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a custom view and override the onMeasure() method.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Create your own `imageView`.
Here is one example

```
public class SquareImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size;
        if(MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ^ MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            if (MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
                size = width;
            else
                size = height;
        }
        else
            size = Math.min(width, height);
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always try setting your own dimensions:

```
android:width="50dp"
android:height="50dp"
```

You'll force it to be exact square that way but you'll need to find the right dimensions yourself. You could also try adding:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

**Additional info**

Actually setting scaleType to *fitXY* is usually very bad. Please check out [ImageView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and use the ScaleType that is most suitable for your use case. If you're not sure which one is best for you, try them all and see how they affect your Image.

Answer (score 3):

It could be done like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: how is your answer different from the "accepted answer" that was posted earlier.

Comment: @AmirDora. "accepted answer" did not worked for me, but I have found that I need to change height of the parent view: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: You could just leave comment to original answer :). Anyways no issue.

Comment: thank you very very mcuh for providing the proper namespace +1

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a small addition to the accepted answer. In my case, the goal was:

1. to display a square image by filling the ConstraintLayout
2. An image with W > H with padding above and below
3. An image with H > W with padding right and left
   To achieve this this line was missing:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

The complete section:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/preview_img_cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/attached_image_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Answer (score -1):

Determine your width/height (for example 40dp), & use a `centerCrop` `scaleType`

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
/>
```