# Android View same Width and Height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Following is my xml code. In my `LinearLayout`. I have two child views , which are aligned using `weightSum`. I have an `ImageView` whose Width is aligned properly due to `weightSum`, but the problem is with its height. I want it's Height to be same dimensions as of its width.
Is there any solution without using static `dp` values.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradien_yellow"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:id="@+id/startbtn"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="@string/start"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_circular"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:id="@+id/tv_challange_title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Early-Bird Challange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_challange_desc"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Take 100 steps five times within.. "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make custom `ImageView`, then set its `height` same as `width`.
[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506373/6229293)

Comment: Its stretching my parent view. Using custom ImageView

Comment: set imageView scaleType to "center"

Answer (score 10):

Found solution by using custom ImageView. 
Its the Best solution. Setting Height same as width in custom ImageView class.

Java code:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

}
```

XML code

```
         <com.mypakage.utils.SquareImageView
            android:background="@drawable/fitbit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: what if it is layout with childs? this code will remove them from parent layout

Answer (score 8):

I think you can do it with your activity's java code.

Something like this one:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams mParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
mParams.height = imageView.getWidth();
imageView.setLayoutParams(mParams);
```

Comment: this is also what came to my mind, i think theres no way to do it in xml code since weights can only include on single orientation. This code will works if you do it properly. If you get a zero width then just add this inside post runnable method or in getViewTreeObserver

Answer (score 1):

You set **ImageView**'s scaleType as centerInCrop

`android:scaleType="centerInCrop"`

Comment: how is this related to the question?

Comment: He just want to set ImageView's Height and Width

Comment: but this answer does not relate on resizing the height and width of imageview

Comment: rather resizing height and width of ImageView better to set the scaleType property. @SecretCoder

Comment: scaletype property does not change the size, the Tread starter want to make the size of the imageview like a square, this does not resize the imageview but resize the content of the imageview to fit inside the imageview. do you get it?

Comment: @SecretCoder For more comment go to chatting, More comment like thread you can go to chatroom, SO is not for chatting

Comment: @Smit.Satodia we are not chatting, we are discussing. For more concern please go to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this just give weights to inner linear layout also

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"`enter code here`
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:id="@+id/startbtn"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="start"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <TextView
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/tv_challange_title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Early-Bird Challange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_challange_desc"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Take 100 steps five times within.. "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use an image with same size on width and height (better .9patch)

```
      <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:id="@+id/startbtn"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="start"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:src="@drawable/background_gradient_circular"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```