# How to get exact height and width of android screen with weight?

Tags: android-linearlayout

I need a square block of 20% of the screen,

- If i get a width of 100 DP then i also need height of 100 DP.

  How to achieve this in android with the use of weight?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
public void setImageSize(byte[] imageThumbnail)
{
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        Bitmap bitmapOrg = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), new ByteArrayInputStream(imageThumbnail)).getBitmap();

        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

        float scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity/5;

        //set image in imageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapOrg);

        //set imageView dynamic width and height
        imageView.getLayoutParam().width = scaleWidth;
        imageView.getLayoutParam().height= scaleWidth;

}
```

Or

Maybe try a different approach...you can create [SquareImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506275/imageview-be-a-square-with-dynamic-width) to scaling of images to screen density of width and height.