# Does android scale images appropriately when we set a different height than was calculated?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

So to make an image square the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506275/imageview-be-a-square-with-dynamic-width) works:

```
public class SquareImageView  extends ImageView {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
  }

  ...

}
```

So my question is:
If I understand correctly we have to call `super.onMeasure` so that the object can figure out its width and height. But when we pass in the `setMeasuredDimension` the `width` both as height and width to make the image square does the Android scale the image?
Any kind of such changes are they scaled properly? Or the best approach is to already have the resource square e.g. from some photo editing tool

Comment: `does the Android scale the image?` No, `setMeasuredDimension` is non-wiser about the `ImageView`, it just specifies the boundaries of the `View`.

Comment: @azizbekian:So how come the image shows up perfect even though I forced it to become square with that code? I don't understand this

Comment: `ImageView` has a default `scaleType` center, thus it will center your image into the view and crop all excessive parts that do not fit in the boundaries. You can experiment with different scale types and see the output.

Comment: @azizbekian:Ah so the image is already pre-processed/scaled and this just crops out based on width/height?

Comment: I would say the other way around: you dictate the width/height of the view, then inside the `onDraw()` based on the `scaleType` of the `ImageView` it would be fitted in the boundaries of the `View`.