# Android How to get the height equal the width of an component

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, components

I want to to have the height of an ImageView equal to it's width. I already read something about using "app:..." in activity.xml.
But, it says that it couldn't find the namespace. After that, I just found a code which didn't worked for me.

Does anybody has ideas or suggestions to fix this issue? If it has to be done programmatically and it would be good if has an example for this using Kotlin.

Comment: Which component you are talking about? Also, show which code you've already tried.

Comment: You can create `custom imageview` and give `height` and `width` same as `width`  refer this link it's in java may be it will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506373/9792247

Comment: I think ConstraintLayout has such function, but as I'm not using it - I can't tel how exactly

Comment: As I said in my question about the ImageView

Comment: @TakeInfos Looks good, but how can I combine this SquareImageView now inside my code? Cuz rn I'm just getting the normal ImageView by the id from the xml

Comment: Put your ImageView into ConstraintLayout I mean

Comment: @Schmidi I have post answer to explain How to use this custom view. You don't have to change height or width programmatically using this custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the height of an ImageView equal to it's width,

**Programmatically [Dynamic way]:**

```
int widthOfImage = image_view.getLayoutParams().width;
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = widthOfImage ;
```

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257851/5705721)

you can do it in **Hard-coded way:**

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

or you can define background like this `image_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#003778" />
<corners android:radius="6dp" />
<size android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

and add it as background in imageView. [remember it is also hard-coded]

Comment: Well hard coded wouldn't be good in my case (sorry that I didn't mentioned that)

Comment: I have added a dynamic way. Check it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this custome view inside you xml file.

Example

```
<YourPackageName.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/squareImageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

Now you have to bind this view in you code. Like Fragment or Activity whatever you have used.

Exmple (This is code in java you can change it in kotlin) :-

> SquareImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id. squareImageview);